# How to mount an IronKey in OpenBSD?

Tags: linux, fedora, openbsd, encryption

Being that it's proprietary, maybe this isn't possible but I was wondering if anybody was successful at mounting one of these in OpenBSD.

I mounted the two partitions the USB drive creates which are `cd1a` and `cd1c` (cd rom emulation).

Then I installed fedora base and turned on linux emulation in sysctl.
`ldd` reveals all dependencies met.
Running `./ironkey` gives:

```
Unable to initialize IKDevCore
```

Some sort of weird fedora error? Can't find any info.

If all else fails maybe I can reformat the drive and just use it as hardware encrypted storage holding softraid partitions.

Answer (score 1):

OpenBSD's compat_linux(8) may be useful for running some things, but interacting with devices?

It's just simple system call translation, that is the extent of the ruse.

How does this utility control the "IronKey"? ioctl(2) to a /dev node, some magic Linux kernel module?

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that's not going to work on OpenBSD.

Also, to MaxMackie, that's unrelated. OpenBSD's compat_linux(8) is i386-only.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the little amount of information I could find](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/qubes-devel/s0DzlHOleFw), this seems to be a Fedora 64-bit issue/bug. I would recommend filling out a bug report and letting the developers know.